# simple php code syntax error

Tags: php

What is wrong with this code. It's giving me syntax error in the editor

```
$posts = if($row['plans'] == 1000) { 2 } elseif($row['plans'] == 1001){ 8 }else{ $row['posts'] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it like this

```
$posts = $row['plans'] == 1000 ? 2 : ($row['plans'] == 1001 ? 8 : $row['posts']);
```

Comment: @DanielA.White That's the first solution that popped into my head, but you're right.

Comment: This does the job and the first answer that worked for me. All other answers works as well. Thanks to all

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign like that. You have to do it like this.

```
if($row['plans'] == 1000) { 
  $posts = 2; 
} elseif($row['plans'] == 1001) { 
  $posts = 8; 
} else{ 
  $posts = $row['posts'] }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($row['plans'] == 1000) { $posts = 2; } elseif($row['plans'] == 1001){ $posts = 8; }else{ $posts = $row['posts']; }
```

or use switch/case:

```
switch($row['plans']){
case 1000:
     $posts = 2;
     break;
case 1001:
     $posts = 8;
     break;
default:
     $posts = $row['posts'];
     break;
}
```

or you can use ternary operators like the codes people already gave you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign value to a variable from `if` condition that way, you should do:

```
if($row['plans'] == 1000) {
  $posts = 2;
}
elseif($row['plans'] == 1001){
  $posts = 8;
}
else{
 $posts = $row['posts'];
}
```

Alternative Syntax (using *ternary* operator `?` ):

```
$posts = ($row['plans'] == 1000) ? 2 : ($row['plans'] == 1001) ? 8 : $row['posts'];
```

More Alternative Syntax (using `switch`) :

```
switch($row['plans'])
{
  case 1000:
     $posts = 2;
     break;
  case 1001:
     $posts = 8;
     break;
  default:
     $posts = $row['posts'];
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're intent on a one-line assignment, it works like this:

```
$posts = ($row['plans'] == 1000 ? 2 : ($row['plans'] == 1001 ? 8 : $row['posts']));
```

`<condition> ? <true> : <false>` (ternary operation)